# Select everything that is recursively linked to one subject

Tags: recursion, sparql, rdf, rdfs

So, I want to select everything that is recursively linked in a particular way to a subject. I know there's no recursion in sparql AFAIK, so I'm hoping there's some other way to solve this.

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX ir: <http://itemrelation.com/ir#>
SELECT ?item
WHERE { ?item a ir:Item .
    { ir:MainItem ir:RelatedTo ?item }
    UNION { ?item ir:RelatedTo ir:MainItem } }
```

This should get all the items the item ir:MainItem has the relation "ir:RelatedTo" to, and all the items that has the relation "ir:RelatedTo" to the item ir:MainItem.

But this is not what I want, I want to get the currently selected items and all the items that are related to the currently selected items in the same manner as they were related to ir:MainItem. Not only that, but I want the items that are related in the same manner to those items too etc...

So, the question is, how do I get all of those items that are "recursively related" to ir:MainItem in the manner described?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With [SPARQL 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/) that's feasible with [property paths](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#propertypaths) like:

```
PREFIX ir: <http://itemrelation.com/ir#>

SELECT ?item WHERE {
    ir:MainItem (ir:RelatedTo|^ir:RelatedTo)+ ?item.
    ?item a ir:Item.
}
```

Starting from `ir:MainItem` the query recursively traverses the `ir:RelatedTo` predicate either in the forward or inverse direction, selects the connected items and filters them to be of `ir:Item` type.